# Integral notation from cartesian from polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, notation

Given an integral $$I=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \cdot \; dx,$$ we can introduce polar coordinates, such that $$I=\int\limits_{\Bbb S^{n-1}} \cdot \; d\theta.$$ Another way to express the latter one is $$\int\limits_{\|x\|=1} \cdot\; dx.$$

Is there an adequate notation, to express the integral in polar coordinates, $$\int\limits_{\Bbb S^{n-1}} \cdot\; d\theta,$$ such that the integral's variable refers to $x$ **and** the integral domain makes clear we are integrating on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some notation like

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} r^{n-1} f(rx) dx dr$$

or if you want to keep the $f(x)$ even

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) dx = \int_0^\infty \int_{r\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f(x) dx dr $$

Comment: The OP might prefer the order of integration to be reversed: $$\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)dx = \int_{\Bbb S^{n-1}}\left(\int_0^\infty f(ru)r^{n-1}dr\right)du.$$